# How to edit a dynamically created row's using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have dynamically created a row in table using jQuery by appending the form data. Now I want to add a function to edit on button click:
When user click on edit button, it should remove the row from table and assign the values again to its relevant fields in the form.

**Code:**

```
<form id="form1" >
      <input  type="text" id="input1"  />
      <input  type="text" id="input2"  />
      <input  type="text" id="input3"  />
      <input  type="text" id="input4"  />
      <input  type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="submit"  />
</form>
```

Comment: Where is `edit` code for already existing rows? You must be having some `javascript or jquery` `events/functions`..

Comment: Create a jsFiddle and it'll be easier for us to help you.

Comment: i actully dont have anyy idea...how to edit the row...thats why i did not write any code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try the following code...
add classes to your append function in each of Td attribute...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#mytable').on('click','.editrow',function(){

    var item1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('.td1').text();
    var item2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('.td2').text();
    var item3 = $(this).closest('tr').find('.td3').text();
    var item4 = $(this).closest('tr').find('.td4').text();
    $('#input1').val(item);
    $('#input2').val(item2);
    $('#input3').val(item3);
    $('#input4').val(item4);
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});  });
```

Comment: i am not good in artificial inteligence ...  just do jquery and other coding as my intrest..

Comment: @HashirAnwaar ...your answer work... just tell me... waht is  " .editrow " ??? +1

Comment: dear @MoizAhmad " .editrow " is class given to the button of edit .